# Properly avoid SQL injection

Tags: sql-server, c++11, odbc

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldescribeparam-function?view=sql-server-ver15#diagnostics) error `Invalid descriptor index` is returned if the parameter is part of the SELECT list.

I'm trying to execute a query

```
SELECT object_id(?);
```

and getting this error.

However the parameter is not really part of the SELECT list.

So how to properly avoid hardcoding the parameter in this case?

I want to query the table id from SQL Server.

Or I will have to hardcode the table name?

EDIT:

I was surprised to see that following:

```
SELECT o.object_id FROM sys.objects o, sys.schemas s WHERE o.schema_id = s.schema_id AND o.name = 'abcatcol' AND s.name = 'dbo';
```

gives different result than just simply

```
SELECT object_id( 'dbo.abcatcol' );
```

I was just trying to avoid table name in the list and place it in the parameter.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include the full query and also fix the typos?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, that is the full query. I'm trying to get the id f the table from the MS SQL internal table. Try it. Also - what typos you want me to fix?

Comment: `obect_id` for `object_id` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, what do you mean? The driver will execute a `SELECT object_id('dbo.customer')`, but 'dbo.customer' should be passed as a parameter to prevent SQL injection. I'm working with C++.

Comment: @Igor, I think Tim is calling out there you misspelled the function name in the query in your question. Since you know the parameter type and length at design time, you should probably be using [SQLBindParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-ver15) here.

Comment: `SELECT object_id(@tableName)` and `@tableName` should be bound as an `nvarchar(128)`?

Comment: @danguzman, I can probably figure it out by looking at the information_schema. But in general this use case needs to be handled properly. Any idea how?

Comment: @charlieface, I presume `@tableName` is ms syntaxes? Is code going to be the same as for `?`?

Comment: @Igor, I don't understand how `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are related to your question. My understanding is you want to get the SQL Server object_id for the specified table name. All you need to do is use a SQL_WVARCHAR parameter with a maximum Unicode character length of 261. That will be large enough for schema-qualified 2-part quoted names.

Comment: Yes correct, only named parameters. `?` is not supported in SQL Server. I think you need [SQLBindParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-ver15) or something to that effect

Comment: @DanGuzman, different DBMSes have different size for those fields (or its possible). Are you saying I should bind the name based on the length of `schemaName.tableName`?

Comment: @Igor, your question is tagged only with Microsoft SQL Server and `OBJECT_ID()` is a proprietary SQL Server function so the code will only work with SQL Server, AFAIK. The max table name length is less for other DBMS products.